# What is the default type evaluation of MonadPlus in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, io, ghci, non-deterministic, monadplus

I have the following code:

```
import Control.Monad

coin :: MonadPlus m => m Int
coin = return 0 `mplus` return 1
```

If I evaluate `coin :: Maybe Int` on the interpreter, it prits `Just 0`. That's normal because of the implementation of Maybe as instance of MonadPlus.

If I evaluate `coin :: [Int]`on the interpreter, it prints `[0, 1]`, because the implementation of `mplus` on list is an `append`.

But if I evaluate `coin`, without any type decorators, it prints `0`. Why? What type does the interpreter 'converts' `coin` to evaluate it?

This code is extracted from: http://homes.sice.indiana.edu/ccshan/rational/S0956796811000189a.pdf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, this is a not super-well documented corner of ghci. When you enter an expression into ghci, it uses the expression's type to decide what to do:

1. `IO ()`: Run the action, do nothing further.
2. `Show a => IO a`: Run the action and `print` the result.
3. any other `IO a`: Run the action, do nothing further.
4. anything else: wrap the whole expression with `print`.

How does it decide which of these types a thing has? Easy: it tries to unify the type of your expression which each of the above signatures in turn and solve all resulting constraints. (For the cognoscenti: this is *in addition* to the extended defaulting rules! This explains why it appears to be defaulting the `m`, even though neither the standard defaulting rules nor the extended defaulting rules say what default to use.)

So, since your expression does not unify with `IO ()` but does unify with `Show a => IO a`, ghci finds `m ~ IO` (and `a ~ Int`) during unification, discovers that there is a `MonadPlus IO` (and a `Show Int`) instance to resolve the constraints, runs your action, and prints the result.

Answer (score 4):

GHCi (but not GHC in general) will, in the absence of a signature specifying otherwise, specialise polymorphic type constructors to `IO` whenever possible. `IO` actions at the prompt, in turn, are executed and have their results monadically bound to the `it` variable, which is then printed (i.e. `do { it <- action; print it }`) as long as there is a `Show` instance for the result type (cf. [Daniel Wagner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53032030/2751851)). For more details, have a look at the [*I/O actions at the prompt*](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#i-o-actions-at-the-prompt) and [*The it variable*](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#the-it-variable) sections of the User's Guide.

In your specific case, it happens that [there is a `MonadPlus` instance for `IO`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4504489/2751851). You get `return 0` from it because `mplus` for `IO` only executes the second action if the first one throws an exception. One demonstration:

```
GHCi> readLn `mplus` readLn :: IO Integer
0
0
GHCi> readLn `mplus` readLn :: IO Integer
foo
1
1
GHCi> readLn `mplus` readLn :: IO Integer
foo
bar
*** Exception: user error (Prelude.readIO: no parse)
```