# I think I found a "non-existent monad"

Tags: haskell, default, monads, ghci

I found a weird feature of Haskell which made me believe I am thinking in the wrong way. I think in Haskell, there should be some *"non-existent"* monad. This is because of the following.

```
Prelude> return 1
1
Prelude> return 1 >>= \x -> if even x then return True else return False
False
```

`>>=` is of type `m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b` where `m` can be any monad. My theory is this: since `return 1` evaluates to a mere `1`, `return 1` can be thought of as a `1` lifted to a value wrapped inside of a *"non-existent"* monad. Haskell captured this fact and evaluated the entire expression

```
return 1 >>= \x -> if even x then return True else return False
```

to `False` since it has to yield a *"non-existent `False`"* which is a mere `False`.

However, I have never heard about such *"non-existent"* monads before.

I am sure I am theorizing it in the wrong way, because if *"non-existent `1`"* is just `1`, the following expression must be type consistent, but it is not. It is a modified version of the above one.

```
1 >>= \x -> if even x then return True else return False

<interactive>:57:1: error:
    • Could not deduce (Integral a0)
      from the context: (Monad m, Integral a, Num (m a))
        bound by the inferred type for ‘it’:
                   forall (m :: * -> *) a. (Monad m, Integral a, Num (m a)) => m Bool
        at <interactive>:57:1-56
      The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    • In the ambiguity check for the inferred type for ‘it’
      To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
      When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall (m :: * -> *) a.
              (Monad m, Integral a, Num (m a)) =>
              m Bool
```

So, there must be a contradiction in my theory. What am I missing?

Comment: See also [What is the default type evaluation of MonadPlus in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53031608/791604).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`return 1` isn't just `1`. What you think is the "non-existent monad" is really `IO`. When you use `return 1`, GHCi is assuming that you mean `IO`, and then helpfully executing the IO expression and displaying the result. You get a type error with `1 >>= ...` because `1` isn't a monad.

As [@bradrn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7345298/bradrn) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57899103/i-think-i-found-a-non-existent-monad#comment102219158_57899118), in general GHCi automatically runs any *`IO a`* value you give it, and then prints out the value *it* returns; if you give GHCi a non-*`IO`* type value, it will just print that value (if it can).

As an aside, there is a monad called `Identity` which essentially does work as a "non-existent monad" as you put it, in that `return x` is isomorphic to `x` no matter what you put in it. It doesn't get used automatically, though; you'd need to manually wrap and unwrap it to use it.

Comment: I think your answer explains another behavior that I observed: GHCI displays the same result for `return (Just 1)` and `Just 1 >>= return`. The former expression itself evaluates to `IO (Just 1)` and it is displayed as `Just 1` since it is wrapped with a `IO` monad. In the latter case the expression evaluated to `Just 1` and GHCI just printed the value out.

Comment: That is correct @Namudon'tdie. In general, GHCi automatically runs any `IO a` value you give it, and then prints out the value it returns; if you give it a non-`IO` type, it will just print the result (if it can).