# MonadPlus IO isn't a monoid

Tags: haskell, error-handling, io, monoids, monadplus

Instance `MonadPlus IO` is unique because `mzero` throws:

```
Prelude Control.Monad> mzero
*** Exception: user error (mzero)
```

So accordingly, `MonadPlus IO` *implies* that it is also intended for errors.

`mzero` apparently serves as the identity element if the other action doesn't throw:

```
Prelude Control.Monad> mzero `mplus` return 0
0
Prelude Control.Monad> return 0 `mplus` mzero
0
```

But it doesn't when both actions throw:

```
Prelude Control.Monad> fail "Hello, world!" `mplus` mzero
*** Exception: user error (mzero)
Prelude Control.Monad> mzero `mplus` fail "Hello, world!"
*** Exception: user error (Hello, world!)
```

So `MonadPlus IO` is not a monoid.

If it violates `MonadPlus` laws when user intends errors, what is it actually intended for?

Comment: Note that `fail` is not intended as a general-purpose method to raise an error; it's an implementation detail for pattern-match failures in `do` notation and list comprehensions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`IO` under `mplus` is a monoid relative to an equivalence class that identifies exceptions. Not that satisfying. An alternative approach might look like this:

```
m <|> n = m `catches`
  [ Handler $ \ ~EmptyIO -> n
  , Handler $ \ ~se@(SomeException _) ->
      n `catch` \ ~EmptyIO -> throwIO se ]
```

The main problem with this approach is that handlers can stack up. When the first action fails, we can't just commit to the second action. A smaller issue is that there's no completely reliable way to determine whether an exception is synchronous (and should be rethrown using `throwIO`) or asynchronous (in which case we need to rethrow it using `throwTo` with our own thread ID). So that way lies messes.